# Recording all vertices on shortest path with igraph?

Tags: r

I am working with a river network where vegetation surveys were conducted (black dots). I would like to:

- calculate the minimum distance between all points and the point highlighted by the red arrow
- for every shortest path between a point and "the red-arrow point" record all points located on that path. For example, the shortest path between the point highlighted by a circle goes through the points highlighted by  rectangles. Therefore, I would to like to to record the unique ID of the "rectangle points".

[image]

I have been trying to use shp2graph and igraph to find a solution but so far I was only able to calculate pairwise distances.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
library(igraph)
library(shp2graph)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)

#Import rivers and points into R

rivers<-readOGR(dsn="/path/to/test_area/",layer="river")
points<-readOGR(dsn="/path/to/test_area/",layer="points_all")


#Assign the points to the river network

ptsxy<-coordinates(points)[,1:2]
ptsxy<-cbind(ptsxy[, 1],ptsxy[, 2])
res.nv<-points2network(ntdata=rivers, pointsxy = ptsxy,Detailed=TRUE, ELComputed = TRUE,approach=2,ea.prop = rep(1, 2))


#Convert to igraph object

igr2 <-nel2igraph(res.nv[[1]],res.nv[[2]], weight = res.nv[[8]])


#Calculate minimum distances between every pair of points

id_num <- as.numeric(res.nv[[3]])
mat_dist<-distances(igr2,v=id_num,to=id_num)
```

The result is a matrix of minimum distances between points.

Here's a link to the data I am currently using:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvjti3b7zp08ruy/sample_data.zip?dl=0

Comment: You might do better on the R-sig-Geo mailing list

Comment: I'd like to help with this but the initial burden of setting up a sample river network shapefile to play with is a bit much. Any chance you can share yours or provide a link to a river network data file we can use? EG  from OSM data: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Eg5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does it.

First read in the data:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(shp2graph)

rivers = shapefile("./sample_data/rivers.shp")
points = shapefile("./sample_data/points.shp")
```

keep the largest connected component - not strictly necessary but helps

```
rivers = nt.connect(rivers)
```

build the node-edge list with the points added in:

```
rivernel = points2network(ntdata=rivers,
                          pointsxy=coordinates(points),
                          ELComputed=TRUE,
                          approach=2, Detailed=TRUE, ea.prop=c(1,1))
```

build the igraph object with distance weights

```
rivg = nel2igraph(rivernel[[1]], rivernel[[2]], weight=rivernel[[8]])
```

the added points are in this component:

```
ipoints = rivernel[[3]]
```

The target point arrowed is point 14 in `points` and so its the vertex number that is 14th in `ipoints`. Now we'll compute the paths from that point to all the vertexes of the points in `points`:

```
sps = get.shortest.paths(rivg, ipoints[14], ipoints)
```

Now let's pick one, the 5th one. Lets get the vertexes from point 5 to point 14:

```
> v = sps$vpath[[5]]
> v
+ 75/1580 vertices, from 757c8ed:
 [1] 1580  317  319 1568  326  327  322  347  334  354  355  356  357  250  249
[16]  248  260  267  276  278  287  289  295  202 1569  203  220  221  219  218
[31]  300  299  282  274  271  270  269  254  253  324  348  349  353  342  314
[46]  320  341  244  243  245  273  204  768  769  773  789  818  370  371  382
[61]  455  468  470  442  441  443  502  475  494  509  507  508  489  471 1571
>
```

We can plot that:

```
plot(rivers)
points(V(rivg)$x[v], V(rivg)$y[v], col="red")
```

But which of those are in our points of interest? Select:

```
ipoints[ipoints %in% v]
[1] 1568 1569 1571 1580
```

Those are the vertexes of the added points that are on the route from point 5 to point 14. To get the corresponding row in `points` subtract this offset:

```
> (ipoints[ipoints %in% v]) - min(ipoints)+1
[1]  2  3  5 14
```

Which tells you the route from point 14 to point 5 also goes through point 2 and 3. Repeat for all the components of `sps$vpath`.

Comment: I'm trying this and i have the following error executing points2network: All the properties of attributs should be specified except EdgeID. Any clues ?

Comment: In fact, I'm getting the same error while trying the example in documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shp2graph/versions/0-5/topics/points2network

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this issue is by using `tidyverse`, `tidygraph`, `sf`, and `sfnetworks`, which will internally use `igraph`:

```r
path = "path_to_data/sample_data"

library(sf)
library(sfnetworks)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)

# Reading in data with sf
points = st_read(file.path(path, "points.shp"))
#> Reading layer `points' from data source `points.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 14 features and 5 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 2920932 ymin: 2188783 xmax: 2953236 ymax: 2226924
#> projected CRS:  ETRS89_LAEA_Europe
rivers = st_read(file.path(path, "rivers.shp"))
#> Reading layer `rivers' from data source `rivers.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 1928 features and 2 fields
#> geometry type:  LINESTRING
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 2914926 ymin: 2182777 xmax: 2959242 ymax: 2232930
#> projected CRS:  ETRS89_LAEA_Europe

# Convert the rivers into an sfnetwork
net = as_sfnetwork(rivers, directed = F) %>% 
  # Obtain the largest connected component
  filter(group_components() == 1)
```

We can get the node indices to which the points features are nearest to as follows, this is not directly needed for calculating the shortest paths since this is done internally by sfnetworks, but we will use it later on to link the points data to the shortest paths node indices:

```r
# Get the indices of the nodes closest to the points features
points_net = st_nearest_feature(points, net)
```

From inspecting the data, "the red-arrow point" should correspond to that with the code "End", which I use below as a from argument. With sfnetworks `sf POINTS` can be directly passed to a shortest paths calculation. The weight argument defaults to the edge length.

```r
# Calculate shortest paths from the "End" point to all other points
# By default sfnetworks uses the edge length as weight
(paths = st_network_paths(
  net, 
  from = filter(points, cod_dqa == 'End'), 
  to = points
))
#> # A tibble: 14 x 2
#>    node_paths edge_paths
#>    <list>     <list>    
#>  1 <int [2]>  <int [1]> 
#>  2 <int [3]>  <int [2]> 
#>  3 <int [23]> <int [22]>
#>  4 <int [17]> <int [16]>
#>  5 <int [72]> <int [71]>
#>  6 <int [44]> <int [43]>
#>  7 <int [46]> <int [45]>
#>  8 <int [33]> <int [32]>
#>  9 <int [17]> <int [16]>
#> 10 <int [10]> <int [9]> 
#> 11 <int [27]> <int [26]>
#> 12 <int [39]> <int [38]>
#> 13 <int [66]> <int [65]>
#> 14 <int [1]>  <int [0]>
```

The previous result is a tibble with node_paths and edge_paths list-columns which can be extracted individually to obtain each path. We can plot the results as:

```r
# We can plot the resulting paths programmatically
plot_path = function(node_path) {
  net %>%
    activate("nodes") %>%
    slice(node_path) %>%
    plot(lwd = 2, col = randomcoloR::randomColor(),  add = TRUE)
}

plot(net, col = 'grey50', cex = 0.5, reset = FALSE)
paths %>% 
  pull(node_paths) %>% 
  walk(plot_path)
plot(points, col = "black", pch = 17, add = TRUE)
#> Warning in plot.sf(points, col = "black", pch = 17, add = TRUE): ignoring all
#> but the first attribute
plot(filter(points, cod_dqa == 'End'), col = "red", cex = 1.5, pch = 17, add = TRUE)
#> Warning in plot.sf(filter(points, cod_dqa == "End"), col = "red", cex = 1.5, :
#> ignoring all but the first attribute
```

[image]

But to obtain the list of points where the shortest paths pass through,
we can mutate over each row to find which point from the original data frame
are part of the `node_paths`, we will save that in a list column. Here we come back to the `points_net` object previously created.

```r
(paths_points = paths %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(points_list = list(which(points_net %in% node_paths))))
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    node_paths edge_paths points_list
#>    <list>     <list>     <list>     
#>  1 <int [2]>  <int [1]>  <int [2]>  
#>  2 <int [3]>  <int [2]>  <int [2]>  
#>  3 <int [23]> <int [22]> <int [3]>  
#>  4 <int [17]> <int [16]> <int [4]>  
#>  5 <int [72]> <int [71]> <int [4]>  
#>  6 <int [44]> <int [43]> <int [4]>  
#>  7 <int [46]> <int [45]> <int [4]>  
#>  8 <int [33]> <int [32]> <int [5]>  
#>  9 <int [17]> <int [16]> <int [3]>  
#> 10 <int [10]> <int [9]>  <int [3]>  
#> 11 <int [27]> <int [26]> <int [3]>  
#> 12 <int [39]> <int [38]> <int [3]>  
#> 13 <int [66]> <int [65]> <int [4]>  
#> 14 <int [1]>  <int [0]>  <int [1]>
```

And we can extract this as a list of lists:

```r
paths_points %>% 
  pull(points_list)
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  1 14
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  2 14
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  2  3 14
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1]  1  4 10 14
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1]  2  3  5 14
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1]  2  6 11 14
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1]  2  7 11 14
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1]  1  4  8 10 14
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1]  2  9 14
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1]  1 10 14
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1]  2 11 14
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1]  2 12 14
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1]  2 12 13 14
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] 14
```